# In Hunter X Hunter, what is Kurapickt's gender?

Tags: anime, hunter-x-hunter

Just that: what is Kurapickt's gender? It's quite confusing, because she sometimes seems female but sometimes, he's male.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hes a guy.  He is referenced to "him or he" a couple times, maybe not in the reboot but in the old one. Here is his ["profile"](http://www.absoluteanime.com/hunter_x_hunter/kurapica.htm).